# mediaSource API not working on Chrome but works smoothly on Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, video-streaming, html5-video, media-source

I am trying to stream a WebM format video being generated using gstreamer and individual frame being sent over websockets. A typical byte arrangement of webm file is like this (you may be already familiar with this).

```
EBML (head size: 12 bytes, data: 16 bytes, pos: 0, '0x0')
    DocType (head size: 3 bytes, data: 5 bytes, pos: 12L, '0xcL') : 'webm\x00'
    DocTypeVersion (head size: 3 bytes, data: 1 bytes, pos: 20L, '0x14L') : 2
    DocTypeReadVersion (head size: 3 bytes, data: 1 bytes, pos: 24L, '0x18L') : 2
...
...
SegmentInfo (head size: 12 bytes, data: 91 bytes, pos: 192L, '0xc0L')
    TimecodeScale (head size: 4 bytes, data: 3 bytes, pos: 204L, '0xccL') : 1000000
    Duration (head size: 3 bytes, data: 8 bytes, pos: 211L, '0xd3L') : 0.0
    MuxingApp (head size: 3 bytes, data: 31 bytes, pos: 222L, '0xdeL') : 'GStreamer plugin version 1.2.4\x00'
    WritingApp (head size: 3 bytes, data: 25 bytes, pos: 256L, '0x100L') : 'GStreamer Matroska muxer\x00'
    DateUTC (head size: 3 bytes, data: 8 bytes, pos: 284L, '0x11cL') : 447902803000000000L
Video (head size: 9 bytes, data: 8 bytes, pos: 295L, '0x127L')
    Pixel Width (head size: 2 bytes, data: 2 bytes, pos: 351L, '0x15fL') : 640
    Pixel Height (head size: 2 bytes, data: 2 bytes, pos: 355L, '0x163L') : 480
    Codec Id (head size: 2 bytes, data: 6 bytes, pos: 359L, '0x167L') : 'V_VP8\x00'
Cluster (head size: 12 bytes, data: 72057594037927935L bytes, pos: 367L, '0x16fL')
    TimeCode (head size: 2 bytes, data: 2 bytes, pos: 379L, '0x17bL') : 1514
    SimpleBlock (head size: 4 bytes, data: 44618 bytes, pos: 383L, '0x17fL') : 'binary'
      track number : 1, keyframe : True, invisible : 'no', discardable : 'no'
      lace : 'no lacing', time code : 0, time code(absolute) : 1514
    SimpleBlock (head size: 3 bytes, data: 793 bytes, pos: 45005L, '0xafcdL') : 'binary'
      track number : 1, keyframe : False, invisible : 'no', discardable : 'no'
      lace : 'no lacing', time code : 27, time code(absolute) : 1541
<<conitnued....>>
```

What I see, the absolute time code and relative time code is being written correctly when I redirect the gstreamer output to filesink. The same gstreamer pipeline is used to extract the byte sequences (samples). These samples are then transmitted over websocket and received on client side using MediaSource API.

My implementation of client javascript is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997477/combining-implementation-of-autobahn-websockets-gstreamers-and-html5-mediasourc).
When I run the client in Firefox, the video runs smoothly without any glitches. But on Chrome, the video freezes after some time or at the beginning.

I tried modifying sourceBuffer.mode = "sequence" or "segments", none of the options work on Chrome, whereas the video feed on Firefox is totally unaffected by any value of "sourceBuffer.mode". The description of these modes is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn903679(v=vs.85).aspx). (I am assuming that the MediaSource API works the same way on IE and Firefox, as no documentation available on Mozilla website).

Also, mediaSource.duration is Infinity/NaN in Chrome and Firefox both.

No matter which way I try, **the live feed on chrome is not at all working, whereas Firefox displays smooth video**. Any suggestions, why this could be happening?

UPDATES:
I upgraded to Chrome version 41 which gives more details on chrome://media-internals. The message that is shown is:

```
render_id: 23
player_id: 1
pipeline_state: kStopped
EVENT: WEBMEDIAPLAYER_DESTROYED
url: blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8080/172f68c8-9ff3-4983-9dcb-    396b3f843752
found_video_stream: true
video_codec_name: vp8
duration: unknown
video_dds: false
video_decoder: FFmpegVideoDecoder
error: Append: stream parsing failed. Data size=2283         append_window_start=0 append_window_end=inf
pipeline_error: pipeline: decode error


Timestamp   Property    Value
00:00:00 00 pipeline_state  kCreated
00:00:00 00 EVENT   PIPELINE_CREATED
00:00:00 00 EVENT   WEBMEDIAPLAYER_CREATED
00:00:00 00 url blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8080/172f68c8-9ff3-4983-9dcb-396b3f843752
00:00:00 00 pipeline_state  kInitDemuxer
00:00:01 687    found_video_stream  true
00:00:01 692    video_codec_name    vp8
00:00:01 692    duration    unknown
00:00:01 692    pipeline_state  kInitRenderer
00:00:01 694    video_dds   false
00:00:01 694    video_decoder   FFmpegVideoDecoder
00:00:01 695    pipeline_state  kPlaying
00:00:10 989    EVENT   PLAY
00:00:11 276    error   Got a block with a timecode before the previous block.
00:00:11 276    error   Append: stream parsing failed. Data size=2283 append_window_start=0 append_window_end=inf
00:00:11 276    pipeline_error  pipeline: decode error
00:00:11 276    pipeline_state  kStopping
00:00:11 277    pipeline_state  kStopped
00:01:14 239    EVENT   WEBMEDIAPLAYER_DESTROYED
```

How to fix or calculate the "append_window_end"???

Comment: I used to have more luck listening to 'updateend' and appending buffers there instead of in just 'update' like you're doing.  Might be worth a shot

Comment: I tried with 'updateend' as well. its still not working with Chrome.